# Flatten jagged array by link of values

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Given a jagged array of integers, for example:

```cs
var arr = new int[11][] {
    new int[] { 0, 7 },
    new int[] { 1 },
    new int[] { 2, 5, 6 },
    new int[] { 3 },
    new int[] { 4 },
    new int[] { 5, 6 },
    new int[] { 6 },
    new int[] { 7, 9 },
    new int[] { 8, 10 },
    new int[] { 9 },
    new int[] { 10 }
};
```

How can it be efficiently flattened to produce a one-dimensional array with items in order of their position and the link between their values. The output for above array should be:

```
{ 0, 7, 9, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 8, 10 }
```

In this particular example, `{ 0, 7 }` and `{ 7, 9 }` will be combined as they have a common number, `7` linking them. Also, following duplicates like `{ 5, 6 }`, `{ 6 }` etc. are removed.

Not sure if it makes enough sense, but I'm scratching my head too :) I'm hoping too much back-referencing and several nested loops can be avoided, if possible, may be using LINQ/PLINQ or some smart in-place string manipulation.

Comment: What if  `{ 0, 7 }` and `{ 7, 9 }` and `{ 7, 10 }` exists in array?

Comment: Do you have a non-efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: The question is not well defined. There are too many cases where it's entirely not obvious what should happen. In your example you seem to imply that sub-arrays can be rearranged at will to produce "shorter" results. What if there are multiple ways to rearrange? Which one should be picked? What if some arrangements produce shorter results than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example result might be found as result of [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of DAG (directed acyclic graph), where pairs of your subarrays form graph edges

{2,5,6} form directed edges (arcs) 2->5 and 5->6.

Topo sort also will discover possible contradictions (cycles) like {2,3}, {3,5}, {5,2}

Comment: Thanks for suggesting topological sorting. It's exactly what I was looking for.